# How does the iPhone encode a float in memory (i.e. hex -> float?)

Tags: iphone, hex

I'm trying to decode packets sent by this application : https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/sensor-data-streamer/id608278214?mt=8 -- it sends sensor data in a udp packet.  I'm using wireshark to look at the contents of the packet, and the header matches the description so I'm looking at the right thing.

I need to decode the raw hex to a float, but everything I've tried (python, web forms, iphone apps) to convert the data results in nonsense.  For example, here is the payload

[image]

The first 4 highlighted bytes are the header.  Then the next 4 are the X accel, next 4 are Y accel, and next 4 are the Z accel.   The values change quickly so it's tough to figure out the exact expected value.  But the mapping should be something (in the order of)

0000ee3b ->  +0.0072

004030bc ->  -0.0215 (some positive or negative number close to zero)

802b80bf ->  -1.0032

I'm assuming they are using some iPhone function to encode the data. Does anyone have any idea what the conversion mechanism is?

Thanks,
reza

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is just little-endian  IEEE-754 encoding.